# jQuery submit() cannot work with click() at the same time?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Basically, I got a form:

```
<div id="butt_click">
    <p><b>3E. Submit</b></p>
    <div id="signup_feedback"></div>
    <form action="#" id="signup_form">
        <p>Email: <input type="email" id="user_email" /></p>
        <input class="sign_up" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
/* for all sign_up buttons */
$('input.sign_up').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('value', 'Please wait...');
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

});

$('form#signup_form').submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var user_email=$('#user_email').val();
    alert(user_email);
    $('#signup_feedback').html('Thanks, ' + user_email +'has been signed up.');
});
```

Only the click event triggered. The form cannot be submitted.

When I delete the whole click() part, the submit() part works fine.

Does anyone know which part goes wrong?

Comment: Why have two different triggers? I'm guessing that your `preventDefault()` is killing the other execution...

Comment: Explore [`event.preventDefault();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: why don't you submit the form from your click handler? That way you can have the logic separated as you have currently and both will trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't do this**. The logic inside the `click` handler on a submit button should (in almost all cases) be the exact same as the logic inside the `submit` handler on the form.

More importantly, **you don't have to `click` the submit button in order to submit the form**, you can just tab to the submit button and hit enter/return, which bypasses your click handler entirely

**Therefore, get rid of your `click` handler completely, and put all your logic inside of your `submit` handler.**

Comment: Thanks Adam. It works fine after I put all the click() into the submit().

Comment: But I got another question: As u see the click() is for all the "Sign_up" buttons. I prefer to keep the function for my "Sign_up" buttons. What should I do if I want to keep this, meanwhile I want some features created by the submit which triggered by the submit button?

Comment: @PrinceLuo - your click handler simply disables the submit buttons, which, again, should be disabled **on submission of the form**, not on click of the button. So simply add a class to all forms that you want to disable the submit buttons for and then create a generic submit handler that does that for you. Like: `$('form.disable-submit-button').on('submit',function() { $('input[type=submit]',this).attr('value','Please wait...').attr('disabled',true); });`

Comment: @Adam-Thanks again. I switch the submit button not to be the "Sign_up" class, and add all the functions into the submit(), making it maintain the general features of my buttons. Looks good now!-

Answer (score 4):

In your click part, you have the code. Read [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This would prevent the default behavior of submitting the form.

Comment: This is not the actual answer , i think so.

Comment: It is accurate - the default action of a submit button is to submit the form, so preventing the default action on clicking a submit button prevents the form from submitting (and thus prevents the `submit` handler from firing). But it's rarely a good idea to have a `click` handler on a submit button and a `submit` handler on the same form.